# How to take form responses from one sheet to update the next?

Tags: google-sheets

References:

- Identifier number is the key field which we are wanting to use to link the two sheets together (this will also be referred to as "id")
- First sheet is the full list of identifiers and the location of were we want to mark x based on the responses of the form.
- Second sheet is were the data is stored for the Google Drive Form, this is the sheet that we are looking for any users placing a identifier so that we can mark the other sheet.

Scenario: I have one Google Drive Spreadsheet that has two sheets inside of it, one that has an identifier number between 1-700 already listed out. The second page is a sheet that stores entries of a Google Drive Form that I made, where the person who submits a form will be forced to enter the identifier number in one of the fields. what I need to do is have the first sheet update by putting an X in one of the fields next to the identifier number when that identifier number exist in the entry form sheet.

Details: for example sake, lets assume that in the first sheet column A is the id, and column D is the field we want to mark X on. Also lets assume that in the second sheet column B is were the id will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that:

> first sheet column A is the id, 
>               column D is the field we want to mark X on.
>
> Second sheet column B is were the id will be.

You can Use a function like this in column D:

```
D2 = VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2, Sheet2!B1:B700, Sheet2!AA2, FALSE)
```

This returns the value from column AA in sheet 2.   To get the exact result you want, you need to be not using that column, and to have put X's into.      But you can combine with `VLOOKUP` formula with others eg. `ISNA()` to get various results.